# Odd result when reading first byte of a PNG header

Tags: c++, png, byte, fread

I'm trying to read the header from a PNG file.

The result should be

```
Dec: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
Hex: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

However, I get

```
Dec: 4294967 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
char T;
pngFile = fopen(Filename, "rb");
if(pngFile)
{
    fread(&T, 1, 1, pngFile);
    fclose(pngFile);
    printf("T: %u\n", T);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be reading a single byte only into a `char`, then printing that char out with an `unsigned int` format specifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

137 is too big for signed char - use `unsigned char` instead...

see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) for limits of data types.